# Why the click event doesn't work twice on $(window).resize()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add a css class when I click on button if **window width** is less than *500px* and another class if width is greater than *500px*. I tried with the following:

```
$(window).resize(function(){ 
  if ($(window).width() > 500) {
      $(document).on('click','#btn',function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          $("#div").addClass("red");
          $("#div").removeClass("blue");
          runFunctionA(); //is different from FunctionB()
      });   
  } else {
      $(document).on('click','#btn',function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          $("#div").addClass("blue");
          $("#div").removeClass("red");
          FunctionB(); //is different from FunctionA()
      });
  };
});
```

<kbd>[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/goHqa/)</kbd>

The click works only if you resize the Codepen iframe window to *<500*, but if is *>500* doesn't work.

Any help is appreciated! Thank you so much!

Comment: Your code works fine, but i'd suggest you not to rebind on the same element multiple times try this http://jsfiddle.net/Alfie/D8fu2/1/ check the width inside click.

Comment: its working fine , I see no issues here in your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below code work based on window width,if window resize happen then you click the button at that time it will check client width and process the function

Try with this,

```
$(document).on('click', '#btn', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($(window).width() > 500) {
        $("#div").addClass("red");
        $("#div").removeClass("blue");
    } else {
        $("#div").addClass("blue");
        $("#div").removeClass("red");
    }
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/a2F3j/3/)